# How use Tailwind-css in a Flutter application

Tags: flutter, tailwind-css

I'm moving the first steps with Flutter and I was wondering if is possible to use tailwinds styles and components.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Well, i don't think there is an equivalent to MaterialApp for Tailwind CSS. but you can try this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/tailwind_colors

And also building your own.

Answer (score 1):

flutter devs for this issue I created a package that can be used as `Tailwind CSS` styling for your flutter projects here you can check it:

https://pub.dev/packages/tailwind_cli